# Is it possible to do sso for http://aws.amazon.com using saml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml

Is it possible to do sso for `http://aws.amazon.com` using saml?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-sso-to-the-aws-management-console-for-multiple-accounts-by-using-ad-fs-and-saml-2-0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS now [supports SAML](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/11/11/aws-identity-and-access-management-iam-adds-support-for-saml-security-assertion-markup-language-2-0/) as of November 2013.

> We are excited to announce we’ve expanded our identity federation to
>   include support for the Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0,
>   an open standard used by many identity providers. This new feature
>   enables federated single sign-on, or SSO, empowering users to log into
>   the AWS Management Console or make programmatic calls to AWS APIs, by
>   using assertions from a SAML-compliant identity provider, such as
>   Shibboleth and Windows Active Directory Federation Services.

More details at this blog post: [AWS Identity and Access Management Using SAML](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/aws-identity-and-access-management-using-saml.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible.They are not supporting SAML or OAuth. For your reference

http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#Do_you_support_SAML_or_OAuth

> UPDATE sep 3, 2014
>
> currently it supports...

Comment: at least it looks like they are open to doing it in the future, saml would be great for our org

Comment: It is now supported as of November 2013.

Comment: Wow that's great.Can you provide any reference for that.

Comment: @downvoter The answer was correct at that time. Please don't do down vote without comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want SSO regardless of the protocol, then AWS offer a roll-you-own SSO 'solution' for management console auth;
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/identity-federation-to-aws-management-console.html